# PHP Sleep but execute whats before sleep

Tags: php, sleep

So I need a little help, is there a better way to have php wait before executing the next line of code?

I tried:

```
$response = $_POST[response];
echo "</br>".$response;
if (strpos($response,'no') !== false) {
    sleep(2);
    echo "</br>";
    echo 'Why not?';
}
```

But this method does not display the

```
echo "</br>".$response;
```

before it sleeps.
It sleeps for the 2 seconds, then displays the response.

How can I get it to echo $response, then wait 2 seconds before is says "Why Not"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 2):

Flush your buffer (**UPDATE**):

```
<?
$response = $_POST[response];
echo "</br>".$response;
ob_end_flush();
flush();
if (strpos($response,'no') !== false) {
    sleep(2);
    echo "</br>";
    echo 'Why not?';
}
?>
```

References: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php, http://php.net/flush

Answer (score 1):

You have to use flush the buffer content to see the results

```php
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ob_start();
$response = $_POST[response];
echo "<br />".$response;
ob_flush(); 
flush();
if (strpos($response,'no') !== false) {
    sleep(2);
    echo "<br />";
    echo 'Why not?';
}
```

I am using both `ob_flush()` and `flush()` as stated in http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php but just see what works. Sometimes only using `flush()` also works, depending on the server config.

*Be aware of gzip/deflate. You can't deflate an output stream and in the middle of it output the buffer. You can either turn it off by using the htaccess or with the 2 first lines of the code*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the output buffer isn't being flushed before the sleep call. You can indeed control this manually as Pentium10 Points out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078873/1461223

Comment: <?php

ob_start();

echo 'Output one.';
ob_flush();
usleep(1500000);
echo 'Output two.';
ob_flush();

?>    This outputs both at once for me.