# Time function using delay sleep wait in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to print the two echo commands with using delay function in php but unfortunately it is not working.the delay time is not working or showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP output text before sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078867/php-output-text-before-sleep)

Comment: can you please send the code here?

Comment: You've got to be kidding me right? Can *you* really not just click on the link and view it?

Comment: thank you.actually i didnt concentrate on the link

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language, so delaying how information is displayed on the front-end can only be managed by CSS and/or JavaScript.

Comment: I think you are not quite right. It's possible to use ob_* PHP functions to perform partial output.

Comment: In php sleep(5)  function reloading the page for 5 second then do some action , but I want first reload the page and after 5 seconds do any action, is this possible in php ( without jquery or script )

Comment: @amit what you want is not possible...php is server site, you need client site...use ajax if you need php function

Comment: @Amit - No, you will need to use JavaScript or CSS to do this.

Comment: i cant use javascript and css there thats the main problem im facing right now.

Comment: If you explain your situation a bit more in-depth in your initial question by clicking 'edit' we will be able to help you more.

Comment: im trying to integrate with the google style spreadsheet api but it gives an permission denied error everytime im trying to fix the issue....