# How to set a timeout in php before echo message display?

Tags: php, timeout, echo, message

I want to display certain message one by one like:

```
settimeout(5);
echo "Message 1";

settimeout(5);
echo "Message 2";

settimeout(5);
echo "Message 3";
```

The `settimeout` function is not correct in php!
So what is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078867/php-output-text-before-sleep, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that needs to be done in Javascript.

PHP does not have a settimeout function.

You could however try thye sleep() method
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php